# checkbox checked attribute not working in reactJS

Tags: reactjs, radio-button, checked, html-rendering

I have a radio button that I am rendering dynamically, But the checked property is not working.

Below is my code.

```
case "6":
                        var vchky = "";
                        var vchkn = "";
                        if(item.answer === "Yes"){
                          vchky= true;
                          vchkn = false;
                        }
                        else if(item.answer === "No"){
                          vchky= false;
                          vchkn = true;
                        }
                        console.log("vchky : ", vchky);
                        console.log("vchkn : ", vchkn);
                          return (
                              <li key={key}>
                                <div class="custom-selection  ml-0 pl-0">
                                  <p>{item.questionText}</p>
                                  <span class="ml-10">
                                    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="customRadio1-11" name="ques-1"

                                     disabled="disabled"
                                     checked = {vchky}
                                      value = "Yes"

                                    />
                                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio1-11">Yes</label>
                                  </span> <span>
                                    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="customRadio2-22" name="ques-1" 
                                    checked = {vchkn}
                                    disabled="disabled"
                                    value = "No"

                                    />
                                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio2-22">No</label>
                                  </span> </div>
                              </li>
                          );
                          break;
```

I debugged and checked that item.answer = "Yes" , but radiobutton for Yes is notting getting checked.

when I inspected the element, there too the checked attribute is present but not getting rendering.

check below screenshot.

[image]

What am I missing? thanks.

Comment: Remove attribute `disabled` ?

Comment: but i have to keep it disabled so that values cant be changed by the user. Its only for viewing.

Comment: Working fine with `defaultChecked={true}` property.

Comment: earlier I used `defaultChecked` attribute only. but it was not working.

Comment: In my test, I used it like `<input type="radio" readOnly defaultChecked />` and working as expected.

Comment: tried, didn't work. My confusion is , when I inspect then that tag is coming as checked, then why it is unchecked in render screen?? Check the screenshot

Comment: Just wondering, does it appear at all if you remove the disabled property?

Comment: @ChristopherNgo if i remove disabled, the button is enabled but answer is still not rendered.